# Guide/help using Dialog with bash scripting

Tags: bash, bash-script, dialog

While I understand how to create menus, no guide I've found teaches how to actually link them to commands

I was hoping to have something like:

```
dialog--clear --title "n00b's spellbook" \
        --menu "Choose thine spell:" 20 51 4 \
        1 "Name of program"  "blah" \
        2 "Name of other program" "blah" \
```

then somehow 1 runs `./program1`
and 2 runs `./program2`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. Missed the point. Did not catch it was the dialog package – @jasonwryan fix of the markup made it more clear. – So this is a complete re-write.

As noted by the man pages; I recommend you [download the source](ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dialog/) and look in 
the examples folder.

If you're in `apt-get` world simply say:

```
apt-get source dialog
cd dialog*/samples
```

A basic example from the yes/no sample (with some modifications):

```
: ${DIALOG=dialog}

: ${DIALOG_YES=0}
: ${DIALOG_NO=1}
: ${DIALOG_ESC=255}


DIALOG_ERROR=254
export DIALOG_ERROR

$DIALOG --title "YES/NO BOX" --clear "$@" \
        --yesno "A simple Yes/No dialog." 15 61

retval=$?

case $retval in
  $DIALOG_YES)
    echo "YES";;
  $DIALOG_NO)
    echo "NO";;
  $DIALOG_ERROR)
    echo "ERROR!";;
  $DIALOG_ESC)
    echo "ESC pressed.";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

The manual page for [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Box-Options) tells where to start:

> **`--menu`** *text height width menu-height [ tag item ] ...*
>
> On exit the *tag* of the chosen menu entry will be printed on dialog's output.

The given example

```
dialog--clear --title "n00b's spellbook" \
    --menu "Choose thine spell:" 20 51 4 \
        1 "Name of program"  "blah" \
        2 "Name of other program" "blah" \
```

appears to be incorrectly formatted since there are three values per line.  Reducing that to something more plausible:

```
dialog --clear --title "n00b's spellbook" \
    --menu "Choose thine spell:" 20 51 4 \
        1 "Name of program" \
        2 "Name of other program"
```

then the *tag* values are `1` and `2`.  By default, dialog's *output* is the standard error, which can be captured by redirecting that, e.g.,

```
tempfile=$(mktemp)
dialog --clear --title "n00b's spellbook" \
    --menu "Choose thine spell:" 20 51 4 \
        1 "Name of program" \
        2 "Name of other program" 2> $tempfile
```

and used in a case-statement:

```
case `cat $tempfile` in
(1) ./program1;;
(2) ./program2;;
esac
```

There are several sample scripts in the [sources](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/#download) for dialog.  The sample scripts execute utility scripts which create and remove the temporary file, as well as allowing testing of [environment variables](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT) which can change the exit-codes of dialog.

By studying the appropriate scripts—for the **menu** widget in this case—you can get a better familiarity with [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html).